# React API response through form onSubmit

Tags: javascript, reactjs, forms, api, react-hooks

I'm trying to make an API call with a User's input and store the response to display it.

The steps I'm taking:

1. storing the user's input through `onChange="handleLocationChange"`
2. sending the input through the form's `onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}`
3. then calling `const weatherData = GetAPIData(API_KEY, this.state.cityID);` to fetch API data
4. in the GetAPIData component I create the hooks `const [weatherData, setWeatherData] = useState([]);` and then return the json API response in the weatherData hook

   I'm breaking a hooks rule (I believe my error is in trying to call a hook after rendering) and getting the following error, but I haven't been able to figure out how to solve for this error:

> Uncaught Error: Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component

#### Class component (main file)

```
import GetAPIData from "./GetAPIData";

class IOData extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      country: "",
      city: "",
      cityID: "",
      APIData: "",
    };
  }

  handleLocationChange = (event) => {
    this.setState({
      city: event.target.value,
    });
  };

  handleSubmit = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    const API_KEY = "*insert key value*";
    this.setState({cityID: "6533961"}); // I think this is also incorrect since it is an event
    const response = GetAPIData(API_KEY, this.state.cityID);
    this.setState({APIData: response});
  };

  render() {
    const { country, city } = this.state;
    return (
      <div>
          <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
              <label>City:</label>
              <input
                type="text"
                name="city"
                value={city}
                onChange={this.handleLocationChange}
              />
            <button type="submit">Go!</button>
          </form>
{APIData}
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

#### Function Component that retrieves the API response (second file, breaks here...)

```
const GetAPIData = (API_KEY, cityID) => {
  const [weatherData, setWeatherData] = useState([]); // I believe it breaks here
  const endpoint = `http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?id=${cityID}&appid=${API_KEY}`;
  
  useEffect(() => {
    fetch(endpoint)
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(data => {
        setWeatherData(data);
        })
  }, [])

  return weatherData;
};
```

Does the solution have to do with having to re-render the class component to make the hooks work? How can I make the API response go through without an error?

Comment: the error is from the GetAPIData Function. It's not a function component. A component should return an element (JSX or a React.createElement)

Comment: From your code your GetAPIData function is returning just data

Comment: React hooks are only valid in the body of a functional component or in other react hooks. If `GetAPIData` is meant to be a custom hook then it is invalid to use in a class-based component. If it is meant to be a component then it can't be invoked as a function, it needs to be rendered in JSX and correctly receive a props object and return valid JSX.